# Proc surveyselect does not give me the requested sample size

Tags: random, sas, sample

I have a simple proc surveyselect to select a sample by strata; the sample size for each strata is read from a separate file. In several strata is not giving me the requested number of units, even if there are enough, example, there are 150 units, I ask for 22 but is giving me 20. I used my regular code, I used it hundreds of times before, nothing fancy; even tried with different seeds :

```
proc surveyselect data=mydata sampsize=sampsize_file
     selectall seed=1234 out=mysample method=srs
;
  strata=strata;
run;
```

Any idea would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please include example data that replicates your issue, both for `mydata` and `strata`.

Comment: Did you check the log? Strata=strata is not the correct syntax so is it throwing an error or warning?